# intellisense is not showing InsertonSubmit

Tags: c#, linq

Its quite weird, i was trying to insert a record in to my db using `LINQ` but ,my intellisense is not showing `InsertonSubmit` property,so am using the below code to insert a record but am just curios to find out what is going on with my visual studio.

```
 public  CreateSapCostCentreList(string Code, string Name,string Manager)
 {
     var db = new SAPLookUpEntities();
     SAPCostCentre SapLookUp = new SAPCostCentre();
     SapLookUp.CostCentreCode = Code;
     SapLookUp.CostCentreName = Name;
     SapLookUp.CostCentreManager = Manager;
     db.SAPCostCentres.AddObject(SapLookUp);
     db.SaveChanges();
     Add(new SchedSAPEntities.SapCostCentreEntities.CreateSapCostCentre());
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `db.SaveChanges();` it appears you are using LINQ to entities.  [`Table<TEntity>.InsertOnSubmit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763516.aspx) is **available with LINQ to SQL**

Comment: thanks a lot Habib to clarify that, i was keep on thinking InserOnSubmit for Linq to Entity. Thanks again.